# How to insert 2 args into 1 Wp_Query for a slideshow

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, custom-taxonomy, article

I need to post articles and pages present in two specific taxonomy in a slider. I tried to merge the $args and $args2 but it gives me an error. Could anyone tell me how to write the code correctly? Thanks!

This is the code:

```
<?php

        $slider_counter = 0;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'slider'
  );

$args2 =  array(
'post_type' => 'page',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'my_taxonomy',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'slider'
    )
)
  );


  $merged_query_args = array_merge( $args, $args2 );

        $query_slider = new WP_Query ( $merged_query_args );


        while ( $query_slider->have_posts() ) :
            $query_slider->the_post(); ?>

        <?php $slider_counter++ ;?>

            <?php $slider_image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post ->ID ), 'slider_img' );?>

            <div class="swiper-slide <?php if ($slider_counter ==1) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $slider_image_attributes[0]; ?>" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."></a>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <div class="dispaly-3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="slider-a"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
        wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: The slider disappears from the page.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, when you merge two arrays that have identical keys the second will override the first, so the result of your merge will give:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => page
    [category_name] => slider
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => my_taxonomy
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => slider
                )

        )

)
```

And that is why the query is probably returning no results.

Comment: You probably need to run two different queries and combine them (not merge)

Answer (score 0):

I found this code:

```
// Set our defaults to keep our code DRY
$defaults = [
    'fields'                 => 'ids',
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'cache_results'          => false
];
// Set query args for query 1
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
];
// Set query args for query 2
$args1 = [
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => '3',
];
$post_query = get_posts( array_merge( $defaults, $args  ) );
$page_query = get_posts( array_merge( $defaults, $args1 ) );

// Merge the two results
$post_ids = array_merge ( $post_query, $page_query ); //. You can swop around here

// We can now run our final query, but first mke sure that we have a valid array
if ( $post_ids ) {
    $final_args = [
        'post_type' => ['post', 'page'],
        'post__in'  => $post_ids,
        'orderby'   => 'post__in', // If you need to keep the order from $post_ids
        'order'     => 'ASC' // If you need to keep the order from $post_ids
    ];
    $loop = new WP_Query( $final_args );

    // Run your loop as normal
}
```

How can I make it work in my case? I tried to integrate it but it gives me an error.